# Is the iOS5 GM identical to the final version?

Tags: ios, developer-program

Are there any differences between the iOS 5 GM seed released to developers and the final version released to the public? If I have the GM installed, do I need to do anything?

Comment: Could also have been closed as off topic - a GM tagged build is something concerning developers - not the general public and we have chosen to limit discussion to generally available software from Apple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No changes in file bytesize at least.  The first GM seed for 10.7.2 was initially marginally different to the final version in some way and was updated, but the iOS 5 release is identical.  No need to change anything.  If you were not already on the GM/release version, it would have complained by today and deactivated your phone...

Comment: That's not true. The 10.7.2 GM and the public release are both 11C74. There is absolutely no difference to the code base. Apple respects versioning. If the version numbers match, they are identical in every single way.

Comment: What I was trying to say, was that unlike for iOS, for Mac OS the GM changed after it's initial release - there were 2 GMs for 10.7.2, the first was 11C73, it was superseded by 11C74.  The final GM and the release version are both the same, but the first GM release was not the final build, and it was updated post labelling it a GM.  This did not happen to iOS, so if you had a GM of it, it did not subsequently get changed prior to release like Mac OS.  I'd appreciate the removal of the down vote if you agree with my clarification.

Comment: Nope. None of them carried the mark of GM. Apple doesn't mark their products with that moniker, it comes from the public. They go strictly by version number. 73, 74, it's a final release when Apple says and again, they go by version number. People only came to believe 73 was a final release, but that didn't make it true.

Comment: OK, but seeing as it was an aside that not actually pertinent to the answer, which I believe stands correct, a comment asking me to correct it is probably politer and more representative than a down vote.

Comment: Actually, 11C73 did carry the GM mark, it went OS X Lion 10.7.2 build 11C71 Seed Note, (no 11C72), OS X Lion 10.7.2 build 11C73 GM Seed Note, OS X Lion 10.7.2 build 11C74 Final GM Release Note, so both 11C73 and 74 were marked GM in some way.

Comment: Misinformation is misinformation. And if it's not pertaining to the answer, you probably should omit it. The replacing of TBA in the installation notes does not equate to a GM tag. The last 3 (including 74) had release notes but clearly only one was the final build. As I said, other that peoples assumptions based on history, Apple does not brand releases GM. That distinction is made by us, the public. It may be a small point but I'd rather not add to the current misunderstanding of the system. Better to go on builds and those don't differ, seeds or public releases. 74 is 74.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1632/discussion-between-stuffe-and-cksum)